# std::sort getting a std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, sorting

```
class RankList {
public:
  struct RankListComparator {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>, double>& a, const std::pair<boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>, double>& b) {
      return a.second >= b.second;
    }
  };

  void push_back(boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> features, double label) {
    m_list.push_back(std::pair<boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>, double>(features, label));
  }

  void sort() {
    std::sort(m_list.begin(), m_list.end(), RankListComparator());
  }

protected:
  std::vector<std::pair<boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>, double> > m_list;
};
```

What is wrong with the sort() above? I am getting a:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

when I call sort(). gdb isn't giving me anything useful either...

I presume the problem has something to do with cause I am in a class?

EDIT: Solved

The problem was this line

```
      return a.second >= b.second;
```

changed to

```
      return a.second > b.second;
```

Answer (score 7):

The comparator you give to `std::sort` must establish a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). That means:

- For all x, it is not the case that compare(x, x) (irreflexivity).
- For all x ≠ y, if compare(x, y) then it is not the case that compare(y, x) (asymmetric).
- For all x, y, and z, if compare(x, y) and compare(y, z) then compare(x, z) (transitivity).
- For all x, y, and z, if x is incomparable with y, and y is incomparable with z, then x is incomparable with z (transitivity of equivalence).

Your original comparator is not irreflexive: `compare(x, x)` is true. Using such a comparator results in undefined behaviour, which you experienced first-hand as a `std::bad_alloc`.