# C++ throwing a std::bad_alloc exception for very small std::vector using std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, memory-leaks, bad-alloc, mingw-w64

I'm working on a project in C++ which deals with comma separated data (CSV).  What I do is reading the data from a .csv file into a vector of CsvRow objects.
So, today I encountered a really weird std::bad_alloc exceptions being thrown in much more weird situations. Namely, the first test case in which I managed to get a little more time until I get the exception thrown was reading a whole csv file into a vector. The file consists of 500,000 rows and its size is about 70MB.  The file was read into memory like a charm, but then after a few seconds into the sorting procedure, the std::bad_alloc gets thrown. It used roughly 67MB of RAM
Note: I'm using boost's flyweights in order to reduce memory consumption.

BUT, this test case was even stranger:
I'm reading a 146KB file with a few hundreds of lines, and this time I got the exception while reading the data into a vector, which is totally ridiculous having a 70MB successfully read previously.

I'm suspecting a memory-leak, but my machine has 8GB of RAM, using 64-bit Windows 8.
I'm using CodeBlocks, and a MinGW 64-bit boost distro.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Here is a chunk of code in which the std::bad_alloc is being thrown:

1. Reading data from a csv file

   ```
   std::ifstream file(file_name_);
   int k=0;
   for (CsvIterator it(file); it != CsvIterator(); ++it) {

       if(columns_ == 0) {
           columns_ = (*it).size();
           for (unsigned int i=0; i<columns_; i++) {
                distinct_values_.push_back(*new __gnu_cxx::hash_set<std::string,                         
                                           std::hash<std::string> >());
           }
       }

       for (unsigned int i=0; i<columns_; i++) {
           distinct_values_[i].insert((*it)[i]);
       }

       all_rows_[k]=(*it);
       k++;
   }
   ```
2. Sorting the vector using a internal struct stored in my class

   ```
   struct SortRowsStruct
   {
       CsvSorter* r;
       SortRowsStruct(CsvSorter* rr) : r(rr) { };

       bool operator() (CsvRow a, CsvRow b)
       {
           for (unsigned int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
               if(a[r->sorting_order_[i]] != b[r->sorting_order_[i]]) {
                   int dir = r->sorting_direction_[i];
                   switch(dir) {
                       case 0:
                           return (a[r->sorting_order_[i]] < b[r->sorting_order_[i]]);
                           break;
                       case 1:
                           return !(a[r->sorting_order_[i]] < b[r-    >sorting_order_[i]]);
                           break;
                       case 2:
                           return true;
                           break;
                       default:
                           return true;
                   }    
               }
           }
           return true;
       }
    };
   ```

Then, I'm using `std::sort()` to sort the vector of CsvRows

```
SortRowsStruct s(this);
std::sort(all_rows_.begin(), all_rows_.end(), s);
```

**This line looks really suspicious, but I could not figure out an easier way to initialize those hash sets.**

```
distinct_values_.push_back( *new __gnu_cxx::hash_set<std::string,                                     
                             std::hash<std::string> >() );
```

Deleting those hash sets in the destructor crashes the program (SIGSEGV)
Oh, and another thing to point out is that I can't use the default 32-bit gdb debugger due to my MinGW being 64-bit.  The 32bit gdb is bugged and won't work with MinGW 64.

**Edit:

Could the** `boost::flyweight<std::string>` **which I use in the CsvRow class cause the problem?**

In addition to that, here is a part of the `CsvRow` class:

```
private:
    std::vector<boost::flyweights::flyweight<std::string> > row_data_;
```

And the overloaded `[]` operator on the `CsvRow` class:

```
std::string const& CsvRow::operator[](std::size_t index) const
{
    boost::flyweights::flyweight<std::string> fly = row_data_[index];
    return fly.get();
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT - SOLVED:** 
So, this question solved my problem, although I didn't even think of it.
Every custom comparator we pass to the `std::sort()` **has to be a strict weak ordering**, that is being:
**1. Irreflexive

2. Asymmetric

3. Transitive

4. Transitivity of incomparability**

More info at :[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170080/stdsort-getting-a-stdbad-alloc) and [This Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings)
Actually, I did not follow the first one (irreflexivity), that is, if both of the `CsvRow` objects are equal, it should not "compare" them and return `true` as if they were okay, but instead return `false`.
I solved the whole problem by only changing the default return value when both `CsvRow a` and `CsvRow b` are equal.

```
bool operator() (CsvRow a, CsvRow b)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
        if(a[r->sorting_order_[i]] != b[r->sorting_order_[i]]) {
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
    return false;  //this line does not violate the irreflexivity rule
    //return true;   //but this one does
}
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.
Remember this solution in case you experience a similar problem.  It's pretty tricky.

Comment: Post the declaration of `distinct_values_`, and I can all-but-guarantee you're correct in that line being absolutely heinous. When you say "Deleting those hash sets in the destructor crashes the program.." - in the destructor *of what*?? From what i see they shouldn't be dynamically allocated *at all*.

Comment: Yeah the line you highlight as suspicious looks like a total memory leak.  You `new` something, dereference the pointer to the thing you just allocated, and then _copy_ the initialized object over to a _different_ new object allocated by `vector::push_back()`.  You never store the pointer returned by `new`, so there's no way you can `delete` it.  Meanwhile, `push_back()` is creating new objects within your `vector` that you're just copying into.  If you try to `delete` those objects, you'll be in a world of hurt; they're part of storage managed by `vector`.

Comment: FWIW, you should be able to completely remove the four characters `*new`.  What happens when you write:  `distinct_values_.push_back( __gnu_cxx::hash_set<std::string,                                    
                             std::hash<std::string> >() );`

Comment: @WhozCraig The declaration of the `distinct_values_` is `std::vector<__gnu_cxx::hash_set<std::string, std::hash<std::string> > > distinct_values_;` which is a vector of `hash_set`s I need for each column.  I tried to remove the `*new` segment and also removed the deletion lines in the destructor of the class they're contained in.

Comment: @JoeZ: I just tried your suggestion, but the same thing happens again.  It reads the data, and then during `std::sort`, i get a `0xFF` exit code.

Comment: All of these appended edits make your question harder to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
distinct_values_.push_back( *new __gnu_cxx::hash_set<std::string,                                     
                            std::hash<std::string> >() );
```

Looks like you are trying to add one default-constructed element to the vector.  There's an easier way:

```
distinct_values_.resize(distinct_values_.size() + 1);
```

Apart from being easier to type, and more generic, it's also a lot more correct: we should not be `new`ing anything here, just creating a single value at the end, and we should let the vector construct it rather than copying it in, which might be wasteful.

And of course we should never try to `delete` these values.

Comment: Assuming `distinct_values` is a vector, I suspect that results in quadratic behaviour rather than the linear behaviour that `push_back` guarantees.

Comment: @AlanStokes: why would you assume such a thing?  Both ways will have similar performance.  Resizing a vector one at a time does the usual double-when-needed thing.

Comment: I tried using the `.resize()`, but the program crashes returning `0xFF`. However, the quadratic behavior doesn't really matter in my case due to a significantly small number of `hash_set` objects I'll need to add (not more than 50). The test case I'm concerned in uses only 2 `hash_set`s.

Comment: There is no quadratic behavior with resize.  Please run your program in a debugger and show us the code around where it crashes now.

Comment: @John Ah, you're right, sorry, it's fine. I was thinking of code I'd seen which repeatedly used `reserve` to increase capacity before inserting, which does behave very badly.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think I figured it out. It is probably the custom comparison struct that trows the `std::bad_alloc`. I just stumbled upon a question regarding this issue, and the guy who solved it suggested a few rules that this custom comparator should follow. I'll just double check that now.

Comment: C++11 has an even easier way: `distinct_values_.emplace_back();`